# jQuery Autocomplete tied to WCF Service ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework

New to ASP.NET MVC and programming, and I have searched high and low for materials on this subject but haven't found a concrete answer for my particular problem.

The project I am working on requires the use of WCF services.  Initially I started with a jQuery autocomplete function that worked, however moving the code to a WCF service has broken some communication.  The autocomplete functionality no longer works

WCF Service

```
public IList<Location> QuickSearchLocation(string term)
    {
        using (var db = new InspectionEntities())
        {
            //return all locations except the reserved "Other"
            return db.Locations
                .Where(r => r.LocationName.Contains(term) && r.LocationId !=    Constants.OtherId)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

The above code is meant to takes user input based on relation to child table.  If user input does not match data in child table, the users entry is saved to an "other" column in the main db.

Controller

```
public ActionResult QuickSearchLocation(string term)
    {
        return Json(_service.QuickSearchLocation(term), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View

```
div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.LocationId,new {data_autocomplete =     Url.Action("QuickSearchLocation", "Inspection")})
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {

    $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete")});
});
```

Any insight on my problem would be helpful.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It is like you kept on using name "the internet" when talking about IE.

Comment: @tereško thanks for the lesson, question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete expects either only labels or labels with values. On the other hand, you're serving it the whole `Location` object.

You should therefore, create a helper class:

```
public class AutocompleteLocation{
    public AutocompleteLocation(Location location){
        label = location.LocationName;
        value = location.LocationId;
    }
    public string label {get;set;}
    public string value {get;set;}
}
```

After this, you should change your `QuickSearchLocation` controller method like this:

```
public ActionResult QuickSearchLocation(string term)
{
    return Json(_service.QuickSearchLocation(term).Select(l => new AutocompleteLocation(l)).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You should also consider not returning all the results but, rather, only first few (10 for example).

Comment: Thanks man the autocomplete is back up, will definitely need to start looking into those helper classes.